Is there an equivalent to "CloudFormation quick-create" to update the existing stack?
I am using CloudFormation quick-create so that users can easily deploy a stack in their AWS account.
However I may update the stack in the future. I want my users to be able to deploy those changes as easily as the initial deploy.
Is there any equivalent to the quick-create, but for updates?
FYI I tried "quick-create" with the existing stack but it fails (because the stack already exists).
